# concatMap not getting subsequent store emits

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have this setup:

```
public listenCampaignSelected(){
  var campaignSelected$ = this.store
    .select(store => store.appDb.uiState.campaign.campaignSelected)
  var campaigns$ = this.store
    .select(store => store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaigns);

  return campaignSelected$.concatMap(
    v => campaigns$, 
    (campaignId,campaigns) => {
      return campaigns.find((i_campaign: CampaignsModelExt) => {
        return i_campaign.getCampaignId() == campaignId;
      });
  })
}
```

and nothing emits except on the first subscribtion.
now values ARE changing in $campaignSelected, I can see the store being updated.

this is how I subscribe:

```
this.yp.listenCampaignSelected().subscribe(
  (campaign:CampaignsModelExt) => {
    this.campaignModel = campaign;
  this.renderFormInputs();
});
```

Now here is the interesting thing, if I change `concatMap` to `switchMap` all works.

so I am trying to understand why switchMap will work in this case and concatMap does not

Comment: Question 1: How are you subscribing to the stream and Question 2: What kind of result to you want to get out of the stream, because right now it looks to me as if you don't even use half of the data but probably are trying to combine the two streams?

Comment: I updated the Q with more details, tx for reading, Sean

Comment: can you please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885283/rxjs-which-merge-operator-to-use-to-listen-to-single-observable-and-move-to-nex

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is, concatMap will not work since the 2nd stream does not change change / fire. Thus you want to use `switchMap` which switches over the new stream regardless of any changes on that stream:

```
  var campaignSelected$ = this.store.select(store => store.appDb.uiState.campaign.campaignSelected)
        var campaigns$ = this.store.select(store => store.msDatabase.sdk.table_campaigns);
        return campaignSelected$.switchMap(v => campaigns$, (campaignId,campaigns)=> {
            return campaigns.find((i_campaign: CampaignsModelExt) => {
                return i_campaign.getCampaignId() == campaignId;
            });
        })
```

Comment: Or you could use the `combineLatest` operator: `campaignSelected$.combineLatest(campaigns$, (campaignId, campaigns) => {...})`

Comment: can you please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885283/rxjs-which-merge-operator-to-use-to-listen-to-single-observable-and-move-to-nex